# Would it produce a mess in my main branch if the upstream squash commits?

Tags: git, github

For some reason, If the upstream merges my PR, I keep being ahead of the upstream by several commits. (For sync. If the local branch is behind, I'd just fetch but there seems to be issues due to diverging histories.)

May this be happening because they compress my X commits into 1 or a few?

In this case the codebase will be the same, but the history of commits completely different, so when they do a change in the branch, I cant merge (and end up rebasing).

Is it the upstream squashing commits giving troubles? Can provide a better insight as to what is happening?

Comment: I consider upstream squashing my commits unfriendliness, to say the least. If they dislike my commits, they shall tell me, and I will adjust the commits accordingly so that they need not be adjusted by them. And, yes, squashed commits cause a lot of head ache, as you seem to observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general principle, *after performing a squash merge, delete the source branch*. If you don't, as you've pointed out, you will have branches with the same *code*, but not the same *history*, and git will be unable to manage future merges between them.

In many workflows, deleting a branch as soon as it's been merged is expected anyway - each feature is a new branch from a shared and protected "master", "main", or "develop", which nobody will commit to directly.

If you need to base a new feature on a previous one which hasn't yet been merged, you can do so, but *as soon as the first PR is merged* you should rebase your second branch on top of the shared branch.

Comment: I see. I shouldn't touch my main but to sync with theirs. Then even when they do naughty things this branch will always be up to date, and the new branches too. Thanks a  lot.